# Parameter field with multiple values not working

Tags: crystal-reports

Setup a Parameter field with multiple values to be used in a SQL query command and it does not work when more than one value is selected, but works fine with one value selected. And yes, the "Allow multiple values" flag is set to True under Options.

I am trying to go from this:

```
EMPBNFIT.BENEFITPLAN in ('CONSUMER CHOICE','HMO', 'HS HMO','HS NETWORK CHOICE','HS PPO BASIC NH RPN','HS PPO PLUS NH RPN','MFS CONSUMER CHOICE','NETWORK CHOICE','PPO BASIC NH RPN','PPO PLUS NH RPN','WAIVE MEDICAL')
```

to this:

```
WHERE EMPBNFIT.BENEFITPLAN in ('{?MyPlans}')
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a coincidence; had the same problem this morning. I was able to make a workaround in Crystal by converting the array of multiple parameters into a single string, then replacing the `IN` section with an `INSTR` comparison.

Make a formula called `ParamFix` with this logic:

```
REPLACE(JOIN({?MyPlans}, ","), "&", "; ")
```

In my case, the different values were separated by an `&`, but you can replace that based on what comes back from the tables. Then replace the `IN` comparison with:

```
INSTR({@ParamFix}, EMPBNFIT.BENEFITPLAN) > 0
```

Comment: Nice solution @4444. I will have to try that one for sure.

Comment: Thanks @4444, I will give it a try. The other option is to upgrade from CR XI to a newer version where the option exist... under Command Parameter with a checkbox for "Allow multiple values".